# How to save and access UserContext.Identity (MVC/C#) for use with AngularJS?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

In my C#, MVC application, I have a page section with a dropdown.  When a selection is made, the MVC controller sets `UserContext.Identity.CurrentProject` to an object.

This is great for accessing on the server-side, however how do I set this up with Angular so that object is accessible from everywhere?

Thanks.

**-- UPDATE --**

I have created my own `UserContext` class in an `Infrastructure` project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AdminWebsite.Infrastructure
{

    public static class UserContext
    {
        public static CustomPrincipal User
        {
            get
            {
                return (CustomPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User;
            }
        }

        public static CustomIdentity Identity 
        { 
            get 
            {
                return (CustomIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity; 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

... where I have created my own custom membership/principal/profile/role providers.

From the Razor view, when I do:

```
<script language="javascript">
    alert("hello: " + @UserContext.Identity.CurrentProject.WebsiteName);
</script>
```

I get `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on `@UserContext` even though I have `@using AdminWebsite.Infrastructure` at the top of the view.

**Global.asax:**

In `Application_AuthenticateRequest`, I have:

```
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
        {


            // Get the GenericPrincipal identity  
            IIdentity ui = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;  

            /* Extract Name, isAuthenticated, AuthenticationType from
                the identity of the GenericPrincipal and add them including 
                any custom properties to the custom identity. I added a 
                few extra properties to my custom identity. */

            CustomPrincipal customPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal(ui.Name);

            // Set custom principal 
            HttpContext.Current.User = customPrincipal;

        }
```

Comment: Where is that razor code located?  Have you confirmed that the user is authenticated?  Where are you setting the current user's identity (in global.asax?)

Comment: Razor code is in a top-level `Layout.cshtml` view.  Updated above where the Global.asax code is located.

Comment: Have you verified that the user is getting authenticated / that the global code you posted is being executed before the razor code is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your masterpage somewhere you'll want to set up something like:

```
var currentProject = '@UserContext.Identity.CurrentProject';
                    // Not sure what version of MVC you're using
```

Then within your App, you could make it a Constant perhaps:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .constant('myConstants', {
        projectName : currenctProject
});
```

Now you can just inject it everywhere it's needed (as a dependency), and access it by `myConstants.projectName`.

But this is the very angular-way of doing it. You could also be lazy and just access `currentProject` as well ;)